# Passing data between service and Controller in multithreading ASP.NET Core Web API environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i'm relatively new to ASP.NET and Multithreading.

**Context:**
I am trying to develop an application that continuously interrogates (every x milliseconds) in background with a thread an api source that returns a series of values (in json).
The thread updates a "*State*" object that is maintained in memory and continuously updated by the running thread.
The application is written in a *ASP.NET Core web API* project.

When the Get API is called i want that the Controller retrieves the *State* Object and exposes it's content over the API.
The final scope is to have a polling API that has an internal state constantly updated and ready to be shown when asked.

I have created a *ServiceProvider* class that when initialized starts a thread that reads, parses the data and load them into a StateHandler Object that uses locks to prevent simultaneous access and has an internal State object ready to be retrieved with GetState() Method.

Actually i instantiate the PositionService into the Program.cs class (i don't know if it is the right choice)

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
public StateHandler StateHandler = new StateHandler();
public ServiceProvider(StateHandler stateHandler)
        {
            StateHandler = stateHandler;
            Thread positionGetter = new Thread(this.RunPosition);
            positionGetter.Start();
        }

        public async void RunPosition()
        {

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);  
            
            while(true)
            {//retrieving data

                string json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(URL); 
                Position position = PositionDecoder.ParseJSON(json);
               //updating the "shared" object
                StateHandler.UpdateState(position, GetCurrentZone(position));

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

The StateHandler class:

```
public class StateHandler
    {
        private State CurrentState = new State(Position.Empty, Event.Empty);
        private static object stateLock = new object();

        public void UpdateState(Position position, int currentZone)
        {
            lock (stateLock)
            {
                CurrentState = new State(position, DetectEvent(currentZone, position.Timestamp));
            }
        }

        public State GetState() 
        {
            lock (stateLock)
            {
                return CurrentState;
            }
        }

        private Event DetectEvent(int currentZone,long timestamp )
        {
            if(CurrentState.Event.ZoneIn != currentZone)
            {
                return new Event(currentZone, CurrentState.Event.ZoneIn, timestamp);
            }
            else return CurrentState.Event;
        }

    }
```

Also there is the (pretty basic) controller class:

```
public class ProviderController : ControllerBase
    {
        public StateHandler stateHandler;
        private readonly StateContext _context;

        public ProviderController()
        {
            //have to find a way to obtain here the StateHandler Class
            stateHandler = new StateHandler();
        }


        [HttpGet(Name = "rest")]
        public ActionResult<State> Get()
        {
            State act = stateHandler.GetState();
            return act;

        }
    }
```

**Problems:**

1. What is the best way to share the StateHandler class to make it accessible from the ServiceProvider class and from the ProviderController class?
2. Is it right to start the ServiceProvider in the Program Class?

Every idea or help is appreciated.
Thank You in advance

I have looked at volatile variables, passing arguments to controller (like InMemoryDatabase), and so on, without appreciable results to obtain the updated state in the Controller Class.

Comment: `async void` is a bug. It should be `async Task` and should be awaited. Using an explicit thread is *also* a bug. All ASP.NET applications are multithreaded - all requests are served by separate threads.

Comment: ^^ There are really a few basic errors, that need fixing, of which `async void` is just one.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's easier to do that correctly than trying to fix this code. `State` is too vague in a web application. It can be user Session state (already available and thread-safe), Cached data (already available and thread-safe) or actual data, which is stored in a database and retrieved as needed. If you cache the database data, you use the Cache.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Thanks for the advice on async Task, i'll fix this (and read docs on the Task topic). I am trying to: retrieve "data" (that i named State) from an API every 500 mills and expose a "refined" version of that data in a Get api.  The operation of retrieving data has to be done in a separate thread that updates the "data" every 500 mills. So, if i poll my HttpGet api, it gets the latest update of the "data". I hope to have explained it better :/

Comment: Go away from the notion of "needs to be done in a separate thread". What you _actually_ need is a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) that polls an api in equidistant time frames and updates an in-memory cache (? could also be a DB) that the API then consumes. And while you are at it reading up on `Tasks` ( I recommend [Stephen Cleary's Blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) additionally), also look into Dependency Injection in asp.net-core.